# Проблема с библиотекой BeautifulSoup, get не работает

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


link = 'https://cspromogame.ru/avatars'
content_num = 0

response = requests.get(url=link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
block = soup.find('div', class_='main_content').find('div', class_='js-infinite-scroll')
images = block.find_all('a', class_='item-avatar')


for img in images:
    img_link = img.find('a').get('href')
    print(img_link)
```

*Добрый день! недавно я начал учиться парсить сайты, но у меня начались проблемы с получением ссылок на картинки, когда в цикле я вызываю метод '**find**' у меня пишет в принте None, если вызываю '**get**', то тогда выдает вот это*

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

*Хотя один раз у меня все же получилось это сделать, но чаще всего происходит именно это.*

Answer (score 0):

Значит в некоторых классах item-avatar нет тегов `a`, поэтому возвращается `None` и возникает ошибка.
Предлагаю сделать, что то вроде этого, за место вашего цикла в конце скрипта:

```
for img in images:
    img_link = img.find('a')
    if img_link:
        href = img_link.get('href')
    print(href)
```

Comment: Не помогло, так же тег <a> есть везде

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


link = f'https://cspromogame.ru/avatars'

response = requests.get(url=link).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
images = soup.find_all('a', class_='item-avatar')
img_link = [img.get('href') for img in images]

print(*img_link, sep='\n')

https://cspromogame.ru//storage/upload_images/avatars/852.jpg
https://cspromogame.ru//storage/upload_images/avatars/879.jpg
https://cspromogame.ru//storage/upload_images/avatars/856.jpg
......
https://cspromogame.ru//storage/upload_images/avatars/1456.jpg
https://cspromogame.ru//storage/upload_images/avatars/916.jpg
https://cspromogame.ru//storage/upload_images/avatars/3969.jpg
```

Comment: Спасибо, и в чем была моя проблема?

Comment: У вас img.find('a').get('href') и у меня img.get('href')